# Metro/modern App issues

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

A lot of metro apps had problem when my PC was running Windows 8.1 - some apps don't have sound while others, e.g., the built-in Movies&TV, just quit after clicked. Now the problems remain the same after upgraded to Windows 10.

The following is the event log of "Movies & TV" crashing. How to resolve the issue?

```
Faulting application name: Video.UI.exe, version: 1.6.1182.0, time stamp: 0x55a77b42
Faulting module name: twinapi.appcore.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16397, time stamp: 0x55af1390
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x000000000006687f
Faulting process id: 0x1720
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0cb401867c3f8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_3.6.11821.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Video.UI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
Report Id: 9ce5648f-a515-4310-9197-a6d712407517
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.ZuneVideo_3.6.11821.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: Microsoft.ZuneVideo
```

Comment: Create a FULL crash dump (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), compress the dmp and share it. I'll take a look at it and maybe I can see the cause.

Comment: I've created a full crash dump and zipped it. It still has the size of 68MB. How to share it?

Comment: I looked at it and I can only see that a module is missing. But I can't see any details because the PDBs miss some data. I've asked my Microsoft contact and I'll reply here when I get an answer.

Comment: my contact was also not able to see which module is not found. Run ProcessMonitor when you try to launch the app. Now stop ProcessMonitor, filter for Video.UI.exe and NOT FOUND entries in the Result column and look if you see what is not found.http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: I used Process Monitor captured and filtered all Result column containing "NOT FOUND" for ProcessName of Video.UI.exe. It found 443845 events. The detail of the these events are, for example, "Desired Access: Query Value", "Desired Access: Read",... etc. The operation are RegQueryValue, RegOpenKey, CreateFile, .... etc.

Comment: share the raw PML log (without any filters applied) on your OneDrive. (compress it first as 7z/RAR to reduce the size) and send me the link again.

Comment: you shared the filtered log. I want the unfiltered one with all data.

Comment: Sent a new one. Also the "Get started" app shows failed to play video when I tried to play video.

Comment: some files related to themes (generic.xbf, generic.xaml). Remove the bad apps and reinstall them again from the store. Also exclude the folder **C:\Program Files\WindowsApps** from your Av suite, maybe it blocks the setup.

Comment: Thanks. I don't install any 3rd party anti-virus software. I think I tried to removed and reinstalled one of the app before but it didn't help. I will try it later. Maybe I should try to remove the sound card driver and video card driver.

Comment: which edition do you use? The N Edition without Media Player?

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 10 from my previous Windows 8.1 pro.

Comment: have you tried to refresh Windows? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10# attention, this removes all desktop programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the N version of Windows 10 - try installing this

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48231

It resolved a similar problem for me.

The N version of windows doesn't have any media related technologies installed.
For more info on this, check

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-8/upgrade-to-n

Comment: I'm not using N. Can I still try the approach?

Comment: @Flou - If you don't have the N or K edition of Windows then you already have the Media Pack installed.  The Media Pack of course has NOTHING to do with Windows Store applications.

Comment: Thanks very much. This finally resolve the issue on my PC since Windows 8. I don't know how my Windows become N version.

Comment: No Problem - I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: ok, my guess with the N Edition was correct. Nice to hear that it was fixed by installing the Media Feature Pack.